# How to get pages.path

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model

I have the following two tables.

I want to get all from menus table and also path from pages table.

I tried it but I am not able to get the pages.path.

Can anyone point out my mistakes please.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menus` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `shortdesc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `page_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `page_id` (`page_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=79 ;
```

Model

```
$this->db->select('*, pages.path');
$this->db->from('menus');
$this->db->join('pages', 'menus.page_id = pages.id');
$res = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
$this->db->select('menus.*, pages.path');
```

?